# What are fundamentals to work on bioinformatic data analysis ?

Tags: networks

Well, I'm a MSc student in Information Technology Engineering, trying to become more familiar in the Complex networks specially Bioinformatic field to get more knowledge of cancer detection by Biochemical data analysis. 
beside python / R language what else should I work on to prepare myself for an academic seminar?

Comment: You need to be much more specific in order to get helpful answers. What analysis are you planning to do and which tools are you currently using? If you want a broader overview of the field, there are many courses, books, and blogs on this topic.

Comment: Which academic seminar (About which topic? what are the ponents?) ? What do you know about biology and health? Are you familiar with experiments performed on the laboratory? BTW this question is quite broad, we can answer about a concrete answerable questions. You could try asking at biostars.org but please add more information to the question in any case